# Accounting for unobserved variability in interval estimation

Tags: confidence-interval, tolerance-interval

My work involves estimating the strength of materials. Essentially, a manufacturer has samples of a material tested for strength, and then we use that data to compute tolerance intervals. However, this question applies to any type of interval estimation.

The issue is that there is variability in the process that we don't capture in the data. We're testing just a few batches over a short period of time, and all data comes from one manufacturing facility. In practice, the process is more variable over time and the material will come from multiple facilities. This leads to estimated intervals that are unrealistically narrow.

So my task is to take a small sample of ~20 observations and produce an estimate that incorporates variability that isn't in the sample. It isn't possible to get a larger or more stratified sample, but I may be able to get historical data that would give me an estimate of how that type of material tends to behave.

I'm looking for any methods or publications that address this problem. The only thread of an idea I have is to use historical process control data to come up with a general estimate of the variability that can be expected from materials of this type, and then apply that to the interval estimation for new materials. I'm uncertain about how to go about doing that though (would Bayesian methods allow this? I'm unfamiliar).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have this outside estimate of variance , incorperate that with the standard variance and use monte carlo methods to generate possible realizations. This is done when one wishes to incorporate the uncertainty in user specified causal variables for SARMAX models ( regression on steroids ! )

In terms of available literature , I am drawing a blank but I will try and do some research.

https://www.probabilitymanagement.org/ might be a good place to start as I have been involved/partnered with Dr. Savage in a similar vein.